# ANT Design Component, how to use Radio inside Table component instead of the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

[image: My table with default checkbox selection with Antd]

Using Ant Design components, i want to use Radio instead of the default checkbox provided in Table component with the rowSelection.

Can I do that? Or if i can't how do i make it so the user cannot select multiple rows? (Only 1 checkbox can be checked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `rowSelection.type` to *radio* (default is *checkbox*)

```jsx
<Table rowSelection={{ type: 'radio' }} ... />
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6j0kw8vy3z)

Comment: This works, i thought i have to combine the antd Radio component into the Table component. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How to clear the radio selection. Clicking on selected radio does not unselect the row.